# Как проверить ациклический ориентированный граф на наличие гамильтонового пути?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, графы

Можно ли проверить путем запуска обхода в ширину/глубину от какой-либо вершины графа? И разумно, ли будет предположить что, если остались непосещённые вершины, значит, что граф не имеет гамильтонового пути?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё-таки я смог это сделать. Сначала произвел топологическую сортировку и в отсортированном порядке проверял, есть ли у начальной вершины путь в следующую(в топологическом порядке), увеличивая счётчик. Если в конце он равнялся количеству вершин, то есть г. путь, иначе нет.

Comment: А назад из последней вершины не нужно попадать? Или вас интересует именно путь, но не цикл?

Comment: Именно путь. Граф дан ациклический.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то нет. Представим

```
1-> 2 -> 3
|
\-> 4 -> 5
```

Ациклический. Ориентированный. При обходе из 1 обойдет все вершины...

Comment: Хм, спасибо, теперь понял. А какой тогда алгоритм можно использовать для проверки?

Comment: Да что-то даже не представляю... Ощущение такое, что для того, чтоб убедиться в его существовании, нужно его найти :) Но могу быть неправ.

Comment: А если,например, использовать поиск сильной связности? И,если в итоге получаем 1 компоненту, то граф имеет г. путь?